# Responsive Interact.jl and PyPlot polar plot

Tags: matplotlib, julia, interactive

Hell everyone,

Using Interact.jl and PyPlot I'd like to make a responsive, good-looking interactive polar plot.

I've managed to get what I`m looking for to a large degree with the following code.

The only downside: this code runs a bit slow such that the whole is a bit unresponsive.

```
using PyPlot
using Interact

fig = figure(figsize=(4,4))
r = [0,1]
@manipulate for θ=-180:15:180;
    θ_rad = 2*pi*θ/360
    withfig(fig) do        
        ax = axes(polar = "true")
        ax[:set_ylim]([0,1.1])
        ax[:set_yticks]([0,1,1.1])
        ax[:set_yticklabels](["","","\$ <\\psi|\\psi> =1 \$"])
        ax[:set_xticklabels](["\$|0\\rangle\$","\$|+\\rangle\$",
                              "\$|1\\rangle\$","\$|-\\rangle\$",
                              "\$|0\\rangle\$","\$|+\\rangle\$",
                              "\$|1\\rangle\$","\$|-\\rangle\$"])

        plot(θ_rad*ones(2),r,color="#ee8d18"); # an outward line
        scatter(θ_rad,1,s=50, c="red", alpha=0.5); # dot on the tip
    end
end
```

I expect the cause of this unresponsiveness to be the fact that with each call of withfig(f) the axes are cleared and have to be recomposed including all the latex xticklabels.

Is there a way (using Julia, Interact, PyPlot) to make this code run faster?

Would it be possible to just change the ydata (the angle) in the @manipulate loop and only compose the x-axis, y-axis and the labels once?

If so how?

Help is much appreciated!